# Partial view action send parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

How do I send array parameters to the action method?

How do I create a array variable? 
partialView.page

I tried that but it did not work.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetDefinationType", "Crew", new { category = "Competency","crew",Person" }); }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the method `GetDefinationType` you have to let it accept a parameter with the name `CategoryOptions`, this will be the class (parameters) you are passing.

```
public class CategoryOptions 
{
      string[] myArray { get; set; }
}
```

This is how to call and use it:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetDefinationType", "Crew", new { category = new CategoryOptions { myArray = new string [] {"Competency","crew","Person"}} }); }
```

Comment: hi cannot I did that but it did not work well                              " initialize object of type 'string ' with a collection initializer "

Comment: Ops, I forgot to add new string [] infront of the array,  I'll edit it

Comment: If you fixed it please mark it as answer so other users know the question is answered.

Comment: The extra object CategoryOptions is unnecessary. Just pass an anonymously typed string array named category.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this in View:

```
@{
    var temp = new[] { "Competency", "crew", "Person" };
}

 @Html.Action("GetDefinationType", "Crew",new{category =temp })
```

Action:

```
 public ActionResult GetDefinationType(string[] category)
 {
   return Content("");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers were almost right, but over-complicated.

If you want to pass an array of strings as a parameter, just pass an anonymously typed array of strings as your named `category` parameter:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetDefinationType", "Crew", new { category = new [] {"Competency","crew","Person"} });}
```

### Use Html.Action, not HTML.RenderAction

Note: `RenderAction` is for use in code blocks (as you have added), but you can just use the simpler `@Html.Action` for *inline Razor code*:

```
@Html.Action("GetDefinationType", "Crew", new { category = new [] {"Competency","crew","Person"} })
```

In either case the controller action method just needs to accept a parameter called category of type `string[]`.

e.g.

```
public ActionRresult GetDefinationType(string[] category)
{
   // do something with the list of categories
}
```

Also, unless you mean the slang combination of `defamation` and `definition`, "`defanation`" please spell it `definition` :)